# Return same Parameter On Some Objects By type

Tags: c#, design-patterns, remove-if

I want that remove my if
what can I do?

I retrieve my data from database and in all of type they have some field
named IsVerified

is anyway that i can remove ifs???

```
private bool CheckDetailsAreVerified(type)
    {
        bool isVerified;

        if (type == sometype1)
        {
            isVerified = this.retrieveFromDB<obj1>()
            .somcondition()
            .All(it => it.IsVerified);
        }
        else if (type == sometype2)
        {
            isVerified = this.retrieveFromDB<obj2>()
            .somcondition()
            .All(it => it.IsVerified);
        }
        else if (type == sometype3)
        {
            isVerified = this.retrieveFromDB<obj3>()
            .somcondition()
            .All(it => it.IsVerified);
        }
        else if (type == sometype4)
        {
            isVerified = this.retrieveFromDB<obj4>()
            .somcondition()
            .All(it => it.IsVerified);
        }

        return isVerified;
    }
```

Comment: Could you use the Factory Pattern with a switch statement?

Comment: no use the case is not reasonable beacase number of my types under 5
and i dont want use if or case

Thank you

Comment: Coud your types implement a common interface containing the `IsVerified` proeprty?

Comment: Could you create a base type with `IsVerified` property like this  `bool isVerified = this.retrieveFromDB<baseType>().somcondition().All(it => it.IsVerified);`?

Comment: can you make `CheckDetailsAreVerified` generic as well, with a type-constraint like `T: SomeCommonBaseType`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Reflection`. Method name and typeName **must be equals**

```
public bool CheckDetailsAreVerified(string typeName)
{
   //"this" == CurrentClass
   var verified = typeof(CurrentClass).GetMethod(typeName).Invoke(null, null);
   return Convert.ToBoolean(verified);
}

private bool Type1()
{
   return isVerified = this.retrieveFromDB<obj1>()
            .somcondition()
            .All(it => it.IsVerified);
}

private bool Type2()
{
   return isVerified = this.retrieveFromDB<obj2>()
            .somcondition()
            .All(it => it.IsVerified);
}
//type3, type4...etc
```

If you need params to method:

```
public bool CheckDetailsAreVerified(string typeName)
{
   //"this" == CurrentClass
   var verified = typeof(CurrentClass).GetMethod(typeName).Invoke(null, 
                                                              new object[] 
                                                              { 
                                                              myIntList
                                                              });
   return Convert.ToBoolean(verified);
}

private bool TypeN(List<int> value)
{
   return isVerified = this.retrieveFromDB<obj1>()
            .somcondition()
            .All(it => it.IsVerified);
}
```

Comment: how I can pass parameters to type methods? i want pass List<int?> to that
for somecondition()
actualy my type method is:
`code`
private bool Type2(List<int?> Ids)
{
   return isVerified = this.retrieveFromDB<obj2>()
            .Where(it => Ids.Contains(it.id))
            .All(it => it.IsVerified);
}
`code`

Comment: @javadandroid `GetMethod(typeName).Invoke(null, new object[] { smthValue1, smthValue2...etc })`. and change signature `TypeN` methods

Comment: public bool CheckDetailsAreVerified(string typeName)
{
   //"this" == CurrentClass
   var verified = typeof(CurrentClass).GetMethod(typeName).Invoke(null, Ids);
   return Convert.ToBoolean(verified);
}

Like this my params is a List<int?> that is created

Comment: No, need `new object[] {Ids}`. I edited my answer, look

Comment: Thank you so much

Only the remain Question is: is Performance  better with if or with GetMethod?

Comment: I'm not sure, but `GetMethod()` can be work faster